# Session still active when database info is deleted

Tags: php

I am modify my register page to allow users in there account after registering, I have made my changes and everything seems to work, the problem I have is if I delete the user out of the database if and you click refresh on a page the requires you to be logged in it still allows that user on that page unless they close there browser

This is how I insert on registering

```
$lastrow = $stmt->insert_id;
$stmt->close();

$_SESSION['ID'] = $lastrow;
```

it auto takes them to there account with a message saying verfiy your email.

then i have this function to check cookie and session if they use the login.

```
/*** If logged in */
function LoggedIn() {
    return isset($_SESSION['ID']) || CheckCookie() ? true : false; 
}
```

this is how i call it on the pages requiring you to be logged in

```
/*** Login required */
function LoggedInRequire(){
    if (LoggedIn()) {} else {
        RedirectToURL(ROOT_URI);
    }
}
```

Comment: If I understood you correctly.. You need to change your structure, currently, you have no way of knowing if a user's account  was deleted or not

Comment: That is because you're setting a session / cookie once the user is logged in. You'll need to tell this cookie to expire / be killed at some point. Considering cookies are client-side, you'll have to get the user to visit a specific page in order to do that. Honestly, I wouldn't worry about it too much; they'll be unable to log in the next time they need to.